# Linking cubic spline smoothing to lowpass filtering

Tags: python, scipy

I was using `scipy.signal.cspline1d()` to smooth out a time series I have. All works fine but now that I want to describe the procedure, I realized that I don't know what the parameter `lamb` actually represents. Of course, I could just report the value that I used, but I think it might be more useful to describe it in terms of smoothing properties that are easier to grasp, e.g. cutoff frequency in low-pass filtering, or number of points that are averaged together, etc.

On the doc page of [spline interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation-in-1-d-procedural-interpolate-splxxx), I found that there is a smoothing parameter that is somewhat linked to the number fitted data points, but couldn't really make from it, how to apply this to my data.

So, is there a straightforward relationship between the `lamb` and some other measure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it helps,

- [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/50df8309b4d927429e14f602cd7b0ba98539929b/scipy/signal/bsplines.py#L270) is the implementation for `cspline1d()` – if `lamb` is not 0,
- it calls [`_cubic_smooth_coeff(signal, lamb)`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/50df8309b4d927429e14f602cd7b0ba98539929b/scipy/signal/bsplines.py#L209), which in turn
- calls [`_coeff_smooth(lam)`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/50df8309b4d927429e14f602cd7b0ba98539929b/scipy/signal/bsplines.py#L188) to acquire a rho and omega value it uses to process the signal given in.

The [18-year-old commit](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/9a2bfdf6bd6813cdabd8f2da8b1a5502996cddef) implementing this doesn't shed too much light on things either, however the function name `_cubic_smooth_coeff` helps a little.

There's [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline#Cubic_spline_definition) that has a promising-looking definition for lambda:

> lambda >= 0 is a smoothing parameter, controlling the trade-off between fidelity to the data and roughness of the function estimate. This is often estimated by generalized cross-validation, or by restricted marginal likelihood (REML) which exploits the link between spline smoothing and Bayesian estimation

Comment: Thanks! I'll check those resources you recommend.